# I need help pleas help me xorg.conf missing Ubuntu 11.10 can't install driver for my Intel GM965 on my Dell Latitude d630

Tags: 11.10, xorg, x11

I have hard time solving my problem. I have searched the net but nothing worked...
I just installed the newest ver of ubuntu 11.10 on my laptop dell latitude d630. Everything works fine but it seems i dont have my video card drivers installed. I have some standart drivers. I try to check out my xorg.conf file but its missing i try to make one from root but it gives me critical error. Its like i dont have X11 installed can some1 please help me here are some of the things ive tryed... 
"""
splash@MDFC:/$ Xorg :1 -configure

Fatal server error:
Cannot open log file "/var/log/Xorg.1.log"

Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help.

ddxSigGiveUp: Closing log
"""

splash@MDFC:/$ sudo cp /root/xorg.conf.new /etc/X11/xorg.conf
cp: cannot stat `/root/xorg.conf.new': No such file or directory
""""
Any ideas help me please...

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu, and many other Linux distros, don't use xorg.conf. If, for some reason, you want xorg.conf, it can be generated.

There is also not need to install Intel graphics drivers, as you probably know, Linux has most open source drivers already included.

In short, don't fix what's not broken. :~)

Answer (score 0):

The only answer given is totally worthless. The question is asked because there is breakage, so flippantly saying "don't fix what's not broken" is silly at best.

Obviously the "autodetection" isn't working or else the question wouldn't have been asked!

Comment: plz post that as a comment